# SQL Query failing on Microsoft Access, working on MYSQL

Tags: php, database, ms-access, pdo

I'm trying to run a query on a Microsoft Access database by doing this

```
$ticket_time = $db->prepare("SELECT problems.start_date,
                                    problems.rep,
                                    problems.id,
                                    tblusers.fname,
                                    tblnotes.id,
                                    tblnotes.note
                                    FROM problems
                                    RIGHT JOIN tblusers ON problems.rep = tblusers.sid
                                    RIGHT JOIN tblnotes ON problems.id = tblnotes.id
                                    WHERE `start_date` > '$history' 
                                    AND status BETWEEN 1 AND 8
                                    GROUP BY start_date
                                    ORDER BY start_date ASC");

$ticket_time->execute();
while ($row = $ticket_time->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    //Do things
}
```

This query works when I'm connected to the mysql database, but the production database is Microsoft Access. This same query, while connected to the MS Access database returns

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line 84
```

With line 84 being `$ticket_time->execute();`

A`var_dump($ticket_time);` returns `boolean false` while connected to the MS Access database, but returns as expected while connected to the MYSQL database which leads me to believe there may be something wrong with the query while connected to MS Access database, but I don't know where to start troubleshooting.

What might be causing this?

Comment: execute the query on MSAcess Database and check ,you are right the queries may differ for different databases  for ex.  in Mysql if you  use limit to get the number of rows in mssql you use top keyword for the same

Answer (score 0):

For one, MS Access does not support backticks to delineate column identifiers, but instead uses square brackets, so you would have to change

```
WHERE `start_date` > '$history'
```

to

```
WHERE [start_date] > '$history'
```

or even

```
WHERE start_date > '$history'
```

Comment: @MichaelN So, was that the actual issue? Is your problem solved now?

Comment: I still haven't fully resolved it, though I've learned I need to add brackets around the FROM table and first JOIN like FROM ((table) RIGHT JOIN ...) this has helped, but there is also an issue with two RIGHT JOINS. I'll update the question as soon as I discover why though.